# Required fields by law for a webshop

Tags: webshop

I am running multiple webshops where I ask the following details from my customers before I allow them to place an order:

Their Full Name, Address (street, city, country, postcalcode), E-mail and Phone number.

Now I got a customer who wants people to be able to place an order (for a digital item) with only their Name (just their first name if they prefer) and E-Mail address.

Is this legal? It's for a digital membership. Where Address details aren't really required to function. But what is required by law?

(ps. I live in the netherlands, don't know if this of huge difference. Tried searching google but couldn't find any detailed information about this)

Thanks in forward

Comment: Might be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Where you are" (a.k.a. jurisdiction) makes a major, huge, **humongous** difference (not to speak about "who you are" and "what you are selling"). The result depends very much on the local laws (country and EU, possibly even local?), and your specific situation.  IIRC (not sure about specifics) the NL has some very special online privacy law since 2009, so you better check with your lawyer - **the question itself is much more about law than programming**.

Therefore, we can't really help you here - 0) law differs significantly across countries, 1) we're programmers, not lawyers, and 2) even if we were, we wouldn't be *your* lawyers. Yes, consulting a lawyer probably won't be free, probably not even cheap; alas, I don't see any other reasonable option.